# Infinite loop somewhere?

Tags: arrays

I'm writing a program to take items from a given .txt file and put them into an array, then from that array, depending on the number, print it out as a character. For some reason it continually prints 3 spaces, then 8 at symbols, creates a new line and repeats, infinitely. I've tried a switch statement (which is commented out) but it did the same thing. cloudberry is the array in which it reads from, and it contains all the correct numbers.

```
while (read.hasNextLine()) {
    int nutmeg = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < cloudberry.length;x++ ){

        for (int y = 0; y < cloudberry[x].length;y++){

            nutmeg = cloudberry[x][y];
            switch (nutmeg){
                case 1: 
                    System.out.print("@");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.print("+");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tag the language. Try stepping through it with a debugger to see what it's doing and why. Please Don't Write Like This As It Is Incredibly Fatiguing To Read.

Comment: Can you please verify that this is the actual code you have? I just put in a suggested edit to make this easier for everyone to read, and you did not close any of your loops.

Comment: I suggest removing the code that's commented out---if it's not doing anything, why have it there? Also, please provide the type of cloudberry. Do your variables have meaningful names (nutmeg, cloudberry, dragonfruit, etc.)? If not, I suggest giving them names that help understand the code.

Comment: Caleb, if you could provide an example of your data here, that would be really helpful.  Also, generally, what language you are using would also be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Your code checks whether there is a new line but you never actually read it, therefore there is *always* the same line to read and the outer loop is iterating infinitely.

The code should be probably something like this:

```
while (read.hasNextLine()) {
   String line = read.nextLine();
   ...
}
```